# Razor templating "Namespace name 'KeywordModel' could not be found"

Tags: templating, razormediator

I'm getting the following error when publishing a DCP using a Razor TBB that has references to the KeywordModel class.

```
TemplateCompileException: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'KeywordModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

[[ code removed]]

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

[[ code removed]]

Stack Trace: 
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating.Compiler.Compile(IEnumerable`1 entries, IEnumerable`1 assemblyReferences)
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating.RazorTemplateGenerator.CompileTemplates(IEnumerable`1 assemblyReferences)
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorHandler.Compile(DateTime revisionDate)
```

The DCPs preview in the CM fine and publish without problems in a different dev environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution (although not the ideal one) you can try by placing following lines in the top of your Razor Template:

```
@using Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
```

and it should be working after that.